# crypto documentation for iota?

Tags: security, documentation

Is there a documentation about the crypto-primitives and the crypto protocols, that are used by iota and how they are implemented?
And if so, where ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point is the IOTA Documentation:

- https://iota.readme.io/docs

As a next step you could look at the actual IOTA Reference Implementation (IRI) on GitHub:

- https://github.com/iotaledger/iri

For the theoretical framework behind all of this you should read:

- https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Detailed documentation on the cryptography of IOTA can be found in the [following page](https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/1.1/cryptography/overview). There is a specific section on the streams in IOTA which is a recent cryptographic construction introduced by IOTA.